# When Programmatically Creating a Post in WordPress, must the Executable php File with wp_insert_post be Located in the wp-includes Folder?

Tags: php, wordpress

I ask this question with the following context:

I want to programmatically create a post in Wordpress using wp_insert_post().

I originally saved the executable php file in the wp-includes folder, but I could not run the php file from my browser, which I wanted to do for convenience.

I saved the executable php file at /public_html/folder/executable_file.php and ran this code from the Chrome browser:

```
<?php
    $postContent = 'test post';
    $title = 'test title';

    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $postContent,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => 'uncategorized'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    echo 'At least the file executed :/';
?>
```

The browser returned

"This page isn’t working

website.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

I have tried several variations of the above code with different errors. I suspect these errors occur because the code is run from another folder, because codex , because even though Wordpress Documentation does not explicitly say it, the post.php example is located in wp-includes. 
(https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

tl,dr; 
Can wp_insert_post be run from outside of the wp-includes folder?

Thank you for saving time by providing this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to run this script outside of the scope of Wordpress. You can't. `wp_insert_post` is a core function of Wordpress and relies on many core aspects of Wordpress (like `$wpdb`), therefore you must be in the scope of Wordpress to run a script using WP functions. This is why you are getting a fatal error.

Furthermore, you don't need to (and you SHOULDN'T) put a file in the `/wp-includes/` directory. The proper way to do this would be to set up a custom theme and put your code in the functions.php file, and then hook into one of the many action hooks Wordpress provides. Something like this:

```
// in your functions.php file, located at /wp-content/themes/your-theme/

function so46492768_insert_post() {
    $postContent = 'test post';
    $title = 'test title';

    // Create post object
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $postContent,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => 'uncategorized'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    echo 'At least the code executed :/';
}
add_action('init','so46492768_insert_post');
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for your input. I think I am running the script within the scope of Wordpress as index.php in the public_html folder contains 

"require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );"

But I think I am understanding that I need to tie everything into the framework, and I did not realize I should be using the functions.php. That is a great help, and I'll be sure to call the function from function.php and report back.

Comment: I can see your misunderstanding if you're new to Wordpress, but you are still not in the context of Wordpress even though you're in the root directory. The "context" of Wordpress refers to its startup and loading methods, and everything (with some interesting fringe exceptions) boils down to your theme folder or initializing your own plugin. Wordpress has a process/routine it goes through to load different scripts and setup the environment. It's not just about being in the same directory.

Comment: Yes, I am new to Wordpress, and Sparticus, you and Mong have greatly helped my understanding of this framework. I added your function to my child theme's function.php and the test post worked like a charm.



Now I just have to make sure it doesn't execute every time I load a page lol, but that's for a different question, and I'd like to see if I can figure it outmyself first. I wish I could select you both, but I think this answer was the simplest route to answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

For what I suspect, it gives you http error code 500 for it cannot find wp_insert_post function because you are calling a wordpress function without even initializing wordpress as you try to run a function directly outside wordpress.

Even putting it inside the wp_includes probably won't do the job.

You have to keep things wordpress. That is, if you use those functions, make sure it's written on a plugin or a theme. But, running the file directly still won't work. you have to let wordpress be initialized so either you call it through an API you have to build yourself, or just run the wordpress site.

[Refer to the WP codex for hooks and filter you can use](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API)

Let me know if this cleared anything out. If it doesn't please let us know what you are trying to do why you want to run it outside wordpress.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am sorry I did not make it clear before. I am running Wordpress on my site, and I am going to try to use the hooks and filter you mention and report back.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I do not have 15 reputation yet, but when I get it I will make sure to upvote you along with Sparticus. You both provided me with great insight into the Wordpress framework.